# Displaying a string and not a integer on an index.html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

After I linked the "program_id" to the accounts table, `rails generate migration AddProgramIDToAccounts program_id:interger` and adding 
`<td><%= account.program_id %>` in the index.hrml.erb file to display the results. However, I'm getting the ID and not the "program name" like in the drop down I created in the _forms.htlm.erb file.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :program %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :program_id, Program.all, :id, :program, {prompt: "Choose a Program"}, {class: "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"} %>
  </div>
```

I'm feeling that I created the migration incorrectly but I'm not sure.

Rails 4.1.8

ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write

```
account.program.name
```

in your index.html.erb file instead account.program_id

Comment: @M.TDavis Welcome. Please accept my answer as it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

With this, you are saying (commented)

```
<%= f.collection_select 
   :program_id, #the parameter name
   Program.all, #the list of objects to use in the select
   :id,  #the parameter value
   :program, #the method you call on each object to get the text you want to display in the select
   {prompt: "Choose a Program"}, {class: "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"} %>
```

So, the select will display the results of calling .program on each Program object.  That feels wrong to me but you don't provide any details of your schema so I can't say for sure.

Comment: that makes sense. I just couldn't process how the syntax would look in my head.But I understand that the parameter along with the method give the end result. It's always something small that drive you crazy. Thanks for the additional input.